# Mock CLLocationManager (swift) for Testing

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, swift, mocking, core-location

### Question 1

Before I actually start writing something myself are there existing frameworks (either obj-c or swift) that wrap CLLocationManager into a mocking framework?

### Question 2

What is the best way to go about making a mock Location Manager?

- Create a class that wraps around CLLocationManager, any calls into that class will return test data or actual CLLocation data depending on what "mode" we are running in
- Extend CLLocationManager and override all the calls I want to "muck" with
- Is there a 3rd option I haven't thought of?

Mostly I'm wondering what the pro/con of each approach would be here assuming there isn't anything already available

[edit]

Although there is a simulate location feature in XCode it does not give me exactly what I need.  If I remember correctly it does not do headings, they have to be interpolated.  Furthermore I may ultimately modify this class to drive CLLocationManager from a flight simulator

Comment: Why don't you use "Simulate Location" feature in Xcode or/and iOS Simulator?

Comment: I need more features than the simulate location feature offers (headings for example cannot be simulated)

Comment: Does it have to be written in Swift?  There are several CL simulators on github such as [this one](https://github.com/progrmr/CLLocationManager-simulator)

Comment: "Simulate Location" won't work for testing. How you found a solution for this one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I thought I'd revisit this question.  What I ended up doing was writing an entire framework to handle Location (and other data) for the app in question.  We are using external GPS sensors.

The class is called `DataManager` and I created a generalized `LocationMessage` type (which can be converted into `CLLocation` with `msg.asCLLocation`).

Part of this mega framework allows for recording of data and file playback, we can drive positions from

- `CoreLocation`
- An **Xplane** plugin
- UDP Streams
- Recorded Files
- External GPS Sensors

So basically the answer is:

> - Create a class that wraps around CLLocationManager, any calls into that class will return test data or actual CLLocation data depending on what "mode" we are running in